# Creating a script which compares the return value from an AT command

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, string, head

I am trying to write a shell script that can save the output of a piped process to a variable. This variable is then compared to a known string in order to discern whether or not my AT modem is connected to a network or not. My problem is when I run my script, the variable never matches the comparator no matter what I do. Minimal example attached. I ran my script in bash -x mode so I could track the variables along the script.

```
connected=$(echo -e 'AT+CREG?\r' > /dev/ttyUSB2 | head -2 /dev/ttyUSB2)
echo "\n"
compare=" $\'\r\' +CREG: $\'0,1\r"
echo "\n"
echo ${connected}
echo "\n"
if [ ${connected} = "${compare}" ] ; then
    echo "This may not be an AT&T card"
else 
    echo "Missed the if statement"
fi
```

Comment: Please, use ShellCheck site (https://www.shellcheck.net/) or tool on your script.

Comment: So what is the value (or variations) of $connected?

If you suspect that the problem is in the non-printable characters, echo the variable in the file, look at the file with `hexdump` and you would know, what do you need to compare the $connected with.